# Adding "email this wiki page" button on Enterprise wiki page

Tags: email, attachments, sharepoint-server

I want to able to add a button on the EnterpriseWiki.aspx page with a certain javascript code that opens Outlook and has the wiki page ( the aspx file ) in attachment so users can easely share content trough email. I allready have a button that prints the entiry page so I assume it is possible to have a similar one to email the aspx file.

Thanks !

Kevin

Comment: What SharePoint version are you using (2007, 2010, 2013)?

Comment: i'm using the 2013 SharePoint server version .

Comment: Perhaps this link will help you craft the script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271171/sending-emails-with-javascript. Using the "document.getElementById('myText').value" might fetch you the page if you know the right Id.

Comment: done it like this : document.all.item('div_mail').innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You need a combination of [mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) and the current URL which you should be able to get from document.URL using JS.

Comment: I don't want to email the link of the page I want to email the content of the page as attachment or add the content of my page to my email I've solved it like this at the moment : function sendMail() {
       var link = "mailto:someone@b-inside.be"
       + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
              + "&subject=" + escape("KB Artikel :")
              + "&body=" + escape(document.all.item('div_mail').innerHTML)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}

Comment: and put the content of the page between div id ="div_mail" tags

Comment: Ah I see.  Good luck